# the app closes if back button is pressed without palying the music

Tags: java, android

I'm new to Android and I wanted to implement a code for controlling the music via seek bar. The following is my activity. The problem with it is that the app force closes when back button is pressed. But when i play the music and press back button the app doesnt cause any problems....

Here is my code:

```
package com.example.acer.aartisangrah;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.Html;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ekdanta extends AppCompatActivity implements Runnable,
View.OnClickListener,SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {
TextView tv4;
Button b9, b10,but19;
int count = 0;
MediaPlayer play;
SeekBar seek_bar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_ekdanta);
tv4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView9);
tv4.setTextSize(22);
tv4.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.thirteen)));
b9 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b9);
b10 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b10);
seek_bar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
seek_bar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
but19 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button19);
but19.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void run() {
int currentPosition= 0;
int total = play.getDuration();
while (play!=null && currentPosition<total) {
try {
Thread.sleep(1000);
currentPosition= play.getCurrentPosition();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
return;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return;
            }
            seek_bar.setProgress(currentPosition);
        }
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.equals(but19)) {
            if (play != null && play.isPlaying()) return;
            if(seek_bar.getProgress() > 0) {
                play.start();
                return;
            }
            play = MediaPlayer.create(ekdanta.this, R.raw.ekadanta);
            play.start();
            seek_bar.setProgress(0);
            seek_bar.setMax(play.getDuration());
            new Thread(this).start();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        play.stop();
    }

    public void increase(View inc) {
        count++;
        if (count == 1) {
            tv4.setTextSize(25);
        } else if (count == 2) {
            tv4.setTextSize(30);
        } else if (count >= 3) {
            count = 3;
            tv4.setTextSize(40);
        }
    }

    public void decrease(View dec) {
        count--;
        if (count <= 0) {
            tv4.setTextSize(22);
            count = 0;
        }
        if (count == 1) {
            tv4.setTextSize(25);
        } else if (count == 2) {
            tv4.setTextSize(30);
        } else if (count == 3) {
            tv4.setTextSize(40);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
        if (fromUser) {
            play.seekTo(progress);
            seekBar.setProgress(progress);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to put your logs when you have this kind of issues. But let's take a guess : in your onPause() method, play should be null if music has not been played. That's why you should check it first. Meaning :

```
if (play != null) {
play.stop();
}
```

Comment: see that there is also an textview  in it.....so if i want to only see the text in the textview without playing the music and press the back button...this causes the app to force close...plz help...nut if i click play and then press back..it doesnt cause any problem

Comment: Edit your question by adding the error  you re seeing as well

Comment: i tried with your code same problem...ill edit the question with logcat

Comment: @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        if(play!=null){
            play.stop();
        }
        super.onPause();
        play.stop();
    }

Comment: why do you put play.stop(); at the end ?
Just do onPause() { if(play!=null){ play.stop(); } super.onPause(); }
because you want to stop the player only once if it's playing. Right?

Comment: i cant even pm you due to badges....i cant explain it properly over here....can i have your email id....

Comment: the problem is that there  has to be two conditions to stops this activity....1st case: there is button to play to play  the music.....if i click that  button & play the music and close this activity by pressing back button it closes perfectly without any for close.....2nd case: if i just open the activity and close this, by pressing back button then the force close happens....thats it....i need solution to handle this case

Answer (score -1):

I think you forgot to add the permission in the AndroidManifest.xml

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```